# Reactor - Flux requires non filter subscriber

Tags: project-reactor

I am using Reactor and am am creating a flux to which I am publishing some events.
My issue is that the subscribers that I create with filters fail after a while unless I add a non filter subscriber on the flux.

```
import reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor

class PublishSubscribe {

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val publisher = EmitterProcessor.create<String>().connect()
        writeAndGet(publisher)
        writeAndGet(publisher)
        writeAndGet(publisher)

    }

    fun writeAndGet(publisher: EmitterProcessor<String>) {
        val result = publisher
                .filter { true }
                .takeUntil { it == "end" }
                .collectList()
                .subscribe()

        val result2 = publisher
                .filter { true }
                .takeUntil { it == "end" }
                .collectList()
                .subscribe()


        Thread.sleep(1000)

        publisher.onNext("unu")
        publisher.onNext("end")

        try {

            println("X=" + result.blockMillis(3000))
            println("Y=" + result2.blockMillis(3000))

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        println(result.isTerminated)
        println(result2.isTerminated)
        println("---")

    }

}

}
```

The code works fine if I an extra subscriber.

```
...
val publisher = EmitterProcessor.create<String>().connect()
publisher.subscribe()  //this solves the issue
writeAndGet(publisher)
...
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Best regards

Comment: how does it "fail"? what is your expectation and what do you observe? on a side note, using a `Processor` should generally be a last resort... maybe you could find a way of doing what you want with `Flux` (eg. `Flux.create`) instead?

Comment: It was failing with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on Mono blocking read. Yaroslav Stavnichiy explains below why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmitterProcessor.create()` creates processor with `autoCancel` flag set to `true`. Which means it gets automatically canceled as soon as all subscribers unsubscribe.

What makes your subscribers unsubscribe is not `filter` but `takeUntil` operator.

Adding an extra *permanent* subscriber keeps processor from auto-canceling but that does not seem to be a good solution.

For your test case to work you have to create processor with `EmitterProcessor.create(false)`. This sets `autoCancel` to `false`, so you can re-subscribe again and again.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!